# is there any more setting rather than web.config redirect rules?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, seo

My website redirects from non-www to www but I dont know why this happens. I have recently installed [url rewrite](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) and the only rewrite tool I have set is the code below and there is no more redirect rule in `web.config`.

```
  <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*?)/?index\.aspx$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

1. Is there any more setting as well as DNS or IIS general settings which causes redirecting from non-www?
2. If I write my own redirect rule (from non-www to www) in `web.config`, does it  override the hidden setting in question 1?
3. Seo checker tools say that search engines see www and non-www as different pages. Does a redirect rule in web.config solves this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DNS is pointing at the correct server for both `example.com` and `www.example.com` DNS names, and that server has a site in IIS with those bindings, then your web.config rule should be evaluated.

Check your DNS here:  https://www.digwebinterface.com/ - enter both
    domains - `example.com` and `www.example.com` on separate lines then
    click dig.  Do both records point at the expected server where your
    web.config resides?

Also confirm the IIS website which contains your rewrite has a binding for the domains. If your site does not have a binding the default site (binding *) will instead receive the request - and use any rewrites found in the default websites web.config.

1. Check your DNS, and check your site bindings, default site web.config and the machine.config file.
2. Assuming your IIS website is receiving traffic for the non-www domain, your rewrite should be evaluated. If your hosting provider/it dept are doing this automatically either globally at a server level, or at the DNS level then theres not much you can do about it (unless you also control those elements...) as the requests will never get routed to your website/rewrite rules.
3. Yes. A 301 redirect to your canonical url will appease the search engines.